# Send File With Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I Want Upload File And Here Is My Scripts:

```js
var progress = $('div.progress');
    $("#file").change(function(ev) {
        var formData = new FormData($("#uploadFile")[0]);
        $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("FileUpload")',
                type: 'GET',
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                xhr: function(ev) {
                    var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                    if (xhr.upload) {
                        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(ev) {
                            var total = ev.total;
                            var position = ev.loaded || ev.position;
                            if (ev.lengthComputable) {
                                var percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
                                var percentText = percent + '%';
                                progress.width(percentText).text(percentText);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return xhr;
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('Data:',data);
                    $('#FileId').val(data.FIleId);
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
 <form  method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadFile">
                        <label>فایل</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
                            <div class="progressContainer">
                                <div class="progress"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </form>
```

Its My Razor Page I Want To When User Clicked Open File And Select Her File Program Send Her request To My Controller And Here Is My Controller

```
 [AjaxOnly]
    public async Task<JsonResult> FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        var root = Server.MapPath("~");
        var dir = Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(root, "Files"));
        var fileName = file.FileName;
         file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(dir.FullName,fileName));
         var fileType = file.ContentType.Split('/');
        using (var service = new FileService())
        {
            var entity = await service.FileCreate(new FileCreateRequest
            {
                Entity = new FileCreateVm
                {
                    Name = fileName,
                    Size = file.ContentLength,
                    Src = dir.FullName+'\\'+fileName,
                    Type = fileType[1]
                }
            });
            return Json(new{ entity.FIleId});
        }
    }
```

but When Request Send To My Controller My Input Controller Is Null!!

Answer (score 0):

My Problem Selved With My Self Actualy Its Need Methode Post

```html
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadFile">
                        <label>فایل</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
                            <div class="progressContainer">
                                <div class="progress"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </form>
```

And Then My Problem Fixed